# Boost 1.65.1 geometry distance strategy compile error with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, boost-geometry

When trying to compile my project with new version of boost 1.65.1, I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\twozn\Dev\soundtoolkit\stk\libraries\boost/geometry/strategies/distance.hpp(101): error C2664: 'int boost::mpl::assertion_failed<false>(boost::mpl::assert<false>::type)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'boost::mpl::failed ************(__cdecl boost::geometry::strategy::distance::services::default_strategy<boost::geometry::point_tag,boost::geometry::segment_tag,boost::geometry::model::point<float,2,boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>,boost::geometry::model::point<float,2,boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>,boost::geometry::cartesian_tag,boost::geometry::cartesian_tag,void>::NOT_IMPLEMENTED_FOR_THIS_POINT_TYPE_COMBINATION::* ***********)(boost::mpl::assert_::types<Point1,Point2,CsTag1,CsTag2>)' to 'boost::mpl::assert<false>::type'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            Point1=boost::geometry::model::point<float,2,boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>,
1>            Point2=boost::geometry::model::point<float,2,boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>,
1>            CsTag1=boost::geometry::cartesian_tag,
1>            CsTag2=boost::geometry::cartesian_tag
1>        ]
```

which is triggered by line

```
std::vector<Value> results;
rtree.query(boost::geometry::index::nearest(Point(p.x, p.y), 1), std::back_inserter(results));
```

where the `rtree` above is defined as

```
using Point = boost::geometry::model::point<float, 2,boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>;
using Segment = boost::geometry::model::segment<Point>;
using Value = std::pair<Segment, size_t>;
boost::geometry::index::rtree<Value, boost::geometry::index::rstar<16>> rtree;
```

The assertion triggered is (boost/geometry/strategies/distance.hpp):

```
template
<
    typename GeometryTag1,
    typename GeometryTag2,
    typename Point1,
    typename Point2 = Point1,
    typename CsTag1 = typename cs_tag<Point1>::type,
    typename CsTag2 = typename cs_tag<Point2>::type,
    typename UnderlyingStrategy = void
>
struct default_strategy
{
    BOOST_MPL_ASSERT_MSG
        (
            false, NOT_IMPLEMENTED_FOR_THIS_POINT_TYPE_COMBINATION
            , (types<Point1, Point2, CsTag1, CsTag2>)
        );
};
```

This compiled and worked correctly with Boost 1.64.0. The compiler is Visual Studio 2017 Update 1. What is the issue here?

Comment: Can you post the relevant bit of the static assertion? It's trying to tell you something, but you clipped it off. (Also, the type of `results`?)

Comment: @sehe I edited the question with (hopefully) relevant bits.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not having access to MSVC, I could /guess/ that you need to include more headers. It could be they got indirectly included in Boost 1.64.0.

See if you can compile the following self-contained example:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b2b53a2e888e4b39)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/geometry/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/core/coordinate_system.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/segment.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/index/predicates.hpp>

using Point   = boost::geometry::model::point<float, 2,boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>;
using Segment = boost::geometry::model::segment<Point>;
using Value   = std::pair<Segment, size_t>;

int main() {
    boost::geometry::index::rtree<Value, boost::geometry::index::rstar<16>> rtree;

    std::vector<Value> results;
    rtree.query(boost::geometry::index::nearest(Point(1, 2), 1), std::back_inserter(results));
}
```

Comment: Thanks @sehe, including `<boost/geometry/index/predicates.hpp>` fixed it

Comment: Looks like the required include may have changed again. Including `<boost/geometry/index/predicates.hpp>` doesn't work for me with Boost 1.67, but taking the lazy way out and including `<boost/geometry/geometry.hpp>` worked fine

Comment: **Boost 1.68**: I had the same problem, I found that both headers `<boost/geometry/strategies/strategies.hpp>` and `<boost/geometry/algorithms/comparable_distance.hpp>` are needed. With those, the long-to-compile `<boost/geometry.hpp>` can be skipped.